# MVC Textbox not accepting empty for nullable int

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, validation

Model

```
public int? SizeLength { get; set; }
```

View

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.SizeLength, new { @style = "Width: 75px" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.SizeLength)
</div>
```

Problem:

When i leave the field empty i get "The field SizeLength must be a number.". Leaving the field empty should be converted to a null value in the returned model. Why do i get this message while my field type is a nullable int?

Answer (score 0):

try `EditorFor`, instead of `TextBoxFor`

not sure if it will work, because the content of the object (either EditorFor or TextBoxFor) is an empty string, not null so you would have to deal with the conversion issue, maybe adding a default value.

Comment: yeah, see my edit, the value is not null, is an empty string, so you would have to deal with the cast yourself

Comment: take a look at the AllowEmptyStrings data anotation

Comment: Doesn't make any difference either. I think you're right about casting the empty string to int?. I need to do that myself.